Add more than one grouping with phase and origin fields in deneb Gantt Chart
We have data in the below format. in this we want grouping in phase and origin fields.
Grouping with phase column is already there but i want one more grouping in this with origin column.

When we try, grouping is not working properly. below is the screen shot.

Data:
{
"id": 5,
"phase": "Design",
"task": "E2E data solution design",
"milestone": null,
"start": "07/03/2023",
"end": "15/03/2023",
"completion": 35,
"origin": "project",
"dependencies": null
},
{
"id": 6,
"phase": "Design",
"task": "Wireframes",
"milestone": null,
"start": "12/03/2023",
"end": "16/03/2023",
"completion": 80,
"origin": "project",
"dependencies": "5"
},
{
"id": 7,
"phase": "Design",
"task": "Prototyping",
"milestone": null,
"start": "13/03/2023",
"end": "22/03/2023",
"completion": 40,
"origin": "project",
"dependencies": 6
},
{
"id": 8,
"phase": "Design",
"task": "Design complete",
"milestone": true,
"start": "22/03/2023",
"end": "22/03/2023",
"completion": 0,
"origin": "project",
"dependencies": 7
},
{
"id": 9,
"phase": "Implementation",
"task": "ETL",
"milestone": null,
"start": "09/03/2023",
"end": "19/03/2023",
"completion": 15,
"origin": "Idea",
"dependencies": null
},
{
"id": 10,
"phase": "Implementation",
"task": "Data modelling",
"milestone": null,
"start": "15/03/2023",
"end": "21/03/2023",
"completion": 40,
"origin": "Idea",
"dependencies": null
},
{
"id": 11,
"phase": "Implementation",
"task": "Measures & KPIs",
"milestone": null,
"start": "15/03/2023",
"end": "17/03/2023",
"completion": 50,
"origin": "Idea",
"dependencies": null

We are trying more than one grouping with 'phase' and 'origin' fields in deneb Gantt Chart. when we try overlapping issue is occurred all over the Gantt chart.

That spec only groups at one level. You'll need to do significant work to adapt it to multiple levels. If you want multiple levels without the work, I suggest this: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7223688570174144512/
